# how to extract data in dict and the print it out line by line?

Tags: python

I have a dict and need to extract the value, group it according to same key and print it. My problem is i dont know how to loop inside the dict and group it.

```
dicts=[{0: 'ATO'}, {1: 'CC'}, {1: 'CD'}, {2: 'GYU'}, {2: 'JOI'}, {3: 'AFD'}]
data =[value for line in dicts for key, value in line.items() if key == 0]
for t in data:
    print(t)
```

my output is

```
ATO
```

my expected output is

```
ATO
CC, CD
GYU, JOI
AFD
```

Comment: Why do you expect that? You have `if key == 0`, so it will only process `{0: 'ATO'}`

Comment: @Barmar yes, i acknowledged it. i did the `key==0` as i mentioned i dont know how to loop it. so i just write what i knew. sorry if that confused you

Comment: this feels somewhat akin to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63257220/in-dictionary-only-last-key-is-printing/63257235?noredirect=1#comment111858355_63257235

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In dictionary only last key is printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63257220/in-dictionary-only-last-key-is-printing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new dictionary whose keys are the keys of the original dictionaries, and the values are lists of the corresponding values.

```
dicts=[{0: 'ATO'}, {1: 'CC'}, {1: 'CD'}, {2: 'GYU'}, {2: 'JOI'}, {3: 'AFD'}]
values = {}
for d in dicts:
    for key, val in d.items():
        if key in values:
            values[key].append(val)
        else:
            values[key] = [val]

for val in values.values():
    print(", ".join(val))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
for g in groupby(dicts, key=lambda x: list(x.keys())[0]):
    print(' '.join(list(d.values())[0] for d in g[1]))
```

**Output:**

```
ATO
CC CD
GYU JOI
AFD
```